# React QRScan component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am using the react library "qrscan" to scan a barcode with my device camera. The problem is when I successfully scan my barcode and get a value, I cannot switch off the camera and therefore the QR continues being scanned and logs the value multiple times. How can I make it that the camera switches off and I only get the initial value from the scan?

Example of code for scanning:

```
const [scanning, setScanning] = useState(false);
const [scannerValue, setScannerValue] = useState('');

const onFind = (value: string) => {
    setScannerValue(value);
    setScanning(false);
    console.log(value);
  };

return (
  {scanning ? (
        <QRScan onFind={onFind} />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <button onClick={() => setScanning(true)}>Scan</button>
          <h4>value: {scannerValue}</h4>
        </Fragment>
      )
  }
)
```

For some reason the QRScan component keeps working even after `scanning` is false.

Comment: Try a different library, the one you're using hasn't been updated in 3 years so there's a chance it has issues with functional components. This one seems to work: https://github.com/JodusNodus/react-qr-reader

Comment: True... Thank you!